# Help new users find the edit feature

Tags: feature-request

Suppose a new user asks a question that deserves close votes (for a reason such as "unclear"), downvotes, or possibly both. After doing either I sometimes leave a comment explaining why I did so. For new users I've grown a habit of ending my comment with:

> ... Note that you can edit your question at any time to improve it (and if substantial it may bump the question, as well as improving chances of getting a great answer).

Or something of the sort.

It might be useful to have the system take over this task, if possible? Something like this:

[image: feature mockup]

I mention this because I think it took me about a year before I learned editing is a part of SO (in any case my first edit was over a year after asking my first question, I see now).

Comment: The close reason, at least for `off topic`, includes this sentence: `If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question or leave a comment.` The substring `edit the question` is a link that lets one... edit the question. So, if someone is new here, his question is closed, and he doesn't bother to read the whole close reason - why should we bother keeping him here? Most other people probably learn about the edit feature by themselves or by looking at the `privileges` list...

Comment: Still, people don't seem to be able to find the edit feature. Helping them find it when it matters most (on the first sight of trouble, instead of after having -10 votes and/or after having been closed) will improve SO overall, and will make us more newbie friendly / less negative. IMHO ;-)

Comment: @Jeroen A pretty significant portion of new users find the edit feature in my experiences, most just don't know *how* to edit a post into good shape.  Those that don't see it given all of the ways they're encouraged to do so are generally people who aren't going to edit their posts no matter what else you possibly add. If you want to see most of the people who would edit their questions but don't, because they don't know they can, look at the people adding answers with additional information to their question. It happens, but quite rarely, and it can be addressed with comments when it happens.

Comment: What Servy said. Also, people don't seem to find the `how to ask` page either. Many new users don't seem to bother to check what is and isn't an on-topic question for SO either. Most don't even know how to format the post with a live preview below it! These are in my opinion way bigger issues - and if it's not even enough to have a post preview and a list of duplicates and a ton of help text for new users, I doubt that a more visible edit feature solves anything.

Answer (score 4):

The close box *already* informs readers that the question should be edited:

[image]

Comment: -2 already? This is a perfectly good answer to the question, it would be interesting to hear what's disagreeable about this...

Comment: Ah, yes sorry, was about to comment. I disagree, I knew about this feature but as foreshadowed by the tone of my question I think we should do *more* to help new users find this "edit" feature (if only for questions with only downvotes and no close votes (yet)). The feature you point out is great, but not enough IMO.

Comment: @Jeroen So you want to tell users when their question is closed that they should be editing the question.  **This does exactly that**.

Comment: Agreed, yes it does exactly that. And it would help to do the same in other places and at earlier moments if possible too. Hence my suggestion in the question. (And hence my downvote, your answer is no substitute for my suggestion imo.)

Comment: @Jeroen It's an implementation of *exactly* what you're suggesting, but it's no substitute for your suggestion?  You're sticking with that?

Comment: It's in a different place (a short bit of text in a rather large bit of text) and at a different time (*after* the question was closed) than the notification I was suggesting. So yes, I'm "sticking" with my suggestion, which I think is *complementary* to the existing link in the close box.

Comment: @Jeroen You do realize that boxes like that visually look like ads, so virtually all internet users train their eyes to not look at them.  Your bright yellow box draws *dramatically* less attention to itself, by virtue of being a banner, than the close notification does.

Comment: Yes, I do realize that. My mockup may not be the best. However, recently a "Naked jsfiddle links are not allowed" notification does stand apart from ads, and in fact was very helpful to me (when editing other's questions). A similar bit of UX/UI might work. I just didn't mean to suggest any specific implementation for UX/UI with my mockup, best leave that to the pros :D

Comment: @Jeroen And "the pros" came up with this option.

Comment: Awhhh cheap shot ;-)

Comment: Let's agree to disagree. You've downvoted my suggestion because you think the current feature already's enough, I've downvoted the answer 'cause I think the question's suggestion would be helpful. Seems fair enough, non?

Comment: @Jeroen I haven't voted on your question at all.

Comment: Ah, my bad then!