# New users cannot edit their question?

Tags: support, edits, new-users

I often find myself in a situation that I need to ask a user in a comment to their question to update it such that it becomes clearer, contains more necessary information or an MCVE, is easier to read, include a link or reference etc.

It has now repeatedly happened that new users (1 to 9 reputation I think) have commented back that they can't edit their own question.

1. Is this true?  (I did not find any document or question related to this. I only found: [Help new users find the edit feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252732/help-new-users-find-the-edit-feature), which is only related to already closed posts.)
2. What are the exact rules on being able to edit one owns question?

Now if this is really the case,
   3. what is the recommended way of handling questions from new users which are in principle valid but need to be edited with information only the questioner himself can provide?

Comment: I use the `[edit]` shortcut in comments, which adds a link to the edit page for the post.

Comment: The biggest problem is that they usually can't find the d̶e̶l̶e̶t̶e edit link on their question.

Comment: @davidism I didn't realize that shortcut existed! Thank you.

Comment: @davidism your shortcut/tip should be more visible for any user. Did you know if there are some meta question with more shortcuts documented?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave it's linked in the help link next to every comment box as well as in the help page about comments: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: To be fair, it's not obvious that `edit` and the other links in that line are clickable. IMHO, it would be easier for new users if they looked like actual clickable buttons, but I guess that's too old-fashioned looking. OTOH, with all due respect, some new users couldn't find their own ... with a map and a flashlight. ;)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It's not true. Users can always edit their own posts if the post isn't locked or self-deleted, and the user isn't suspended.

Comment: Could it be that a suggested edit is pending?

Comment: @Fermiparadox In that case, the edit button would be shown as `edit (1)`, and be clickable to show the suggestion which the owner could unilaterally handle.

Comment: One exception to this: rate limiting. [The complete rate-limiting guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/168333) on MSE points this out for edits on one's own posts. "5 edits on own posts per day, more for high-rep users (scales with reputation), does not apply to ♦ mods".

Answer (score 31):

One common case where this is *sort-of* true is when a user does not log in with the identical credentials.  They may have the same display name, but have logged in with another account (either an older one, or a newer one).  In that case they may not be able to.  I've seen that a few times; in each case, their accounts were simply merged and the ability restored, once they flagged a moderator.

Edit: 
Here's an example, from [Personal Finance and Money](http://money.stackexchange.com):

[Original question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/75927/buying-car-as-s-corp)

[New question posted because user could not comment/edit](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/75947/car-under-s-corp-what-about-the-expenses)

Answer (score 3):

In some situations, it happens that a pending suggested edit is queued. The edit button becomes a shortcut to the review item, and the OP find themselves unable to make their own edit until the suggested edit gets reviewed.

In that case, the OP may comment back that they can't edit their own question.

But if the pending suggested edit was rejected and you discover the comment later, you won't find immediate evidence that edition was unavailable for a short time.

Comment: The op can reject or approve all edits on their posts